# How to reset a PYQT5 progress bar once a certain value has been reached/set?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, progress-bar

I am currently in the process of creating basic GUI which ties together some data analysis scripts.
These scripts can take (depending on the data inputted) a couple of minutes to run and I was hoping to incorporate a progress bar into the GUI for confirmation that the scripts are running.

However, as a self taught python(er) I am having some difficulty implementing solutions to my issue. I can update the progress bar when I run the Open_Instructions method but when I run the Open_generic method the progress bar continuously cycles between 20, 40 and 60% and does not complete. Below is my script. Note - I have removed non-essential(?) lines

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def Open_Instructions(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self.centralwidget)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Increase_Instructions)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        url = 'https://github.com/Example'
        path = os.path.join(main_path,
                        'Manual',
                        'Example.pdf')
        open_resource(path, url)

    def Increase_Instructions(self):
        self.progressBar.setValue(self.progressBar.value()+20)

    def reset(self):
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)

    def Open_Generic(self):
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self.centralwidget)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.reset)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Increase_Instructions)
        self.timer.start(2000)
        path = os.path.join(main_path,
                        'Resources',
                        'Generic_Example.pdf')
        open_resource(path)

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(521, 704)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(MainWindow)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(128, 670, 300, 25)
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.progressBar.setMaximum(100)
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
    
        self.Instruction_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Instruction_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(55, 210, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.Instruction_Button.setFont(font)
        self.Instruction_Button.clicked.connect(self.Open_Instructions)
        self.Instruction_Button.setObjectName("Instruction_Button")
        self.Instruction_Button.raise_()
    
        self.Generic_Datasheet_Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Generic_Datasheet_Button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 450, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.Generic_Datasheet_Button.setFont(font)
        self.Generic_Datasheet_Button.setText("Generic datasheet")
        self.Generic_Datasheet_Button.setObjectName("Generic_Datasheet_Button")
        self.Generic_Datasheet_Button.clicked.connect(self.Open_Generic)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Remove the line `self.timer.timeout.connect(self.reset)` in the `Open_Generic` function, as it results in always resetting the progress bar. Also do not modify files generated by `pyuic`, they should be left as they are; read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Hi, as suggested removing the line does stop the progress bar from constantly resetting, but I am now left with a progress bar which can be only be used once as it remains at 100%, hence why I tried using the reset method in the first place. Regarding the the generated pyuic file, are my progress bar issues because I modified the pyuic file?

Comment: No, the issue is not related to the fact that you're using a pyuic file, but it makes the code unnecessarily confusing (which might potentially increase the possibility of bugs). Besides that, you should be more clear on how/when you want to reset the progress bar: should it reset *as soon* as it reaches the maximum (meaning that 100 will never be "seen")? should it restart on the next cycle, *after* it has reached the maximum? Should the timer stop or continue after that?

Comment: I see thank you, I will read the Deisgner documentation again. Regarding the progress bar, I was hoping for the progress bar to reach maximum (100%) and stay their either for an arbitrary amount of time (say 5 seconds), or remain at maximum value untill another method is used and the progress would reset back to 0% and would start to progress again whilst the second method is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reset the progress bar value, you need to check if it has reached its maximum; if you also want to delay the reset, you'll need *another* different timer to do so, being careful to stop it as soon as a new process is started: if the reset timer has an interval bigger than the one increasing the value, it might reset the progress bar while it is already showing a value bigger than 0.

Note that you should reuse existing timers, and not create a new one each time, otherwise you'll end up with multiple concurrent timers.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.resetRadio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('Reset after end')
        layout.addWidget(self.resetRadio)
        self.resetRadio.setChecked(True)
        self.keepRadio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('Keep value after end')
        layout.addWidget(self.keepRadio)
        self.startButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        layout.addWidget(self.startButton)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.startTimer)

        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=1000, timeout=self.timeout)
        self.resetTimer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=2000, timeout=self.progressBar.reset, singleShot=True)

    def startTimer(self):
        # stop the reset timer if it's running
        self.resetTimer.stop()
        self.progressBar.setValue(0)
        self.timer.start()

    def timeout(self):
        if self.progressBar.value() == self.progressBar.maximum():
            # the maximum has been reached, stop the timer
            self.timer.stop()
            if self.resetRadio.isChecked():
                # we are going to reset the progress bar, let's start the timer
                # that will do that
                self.resetTimer.start()
        else:
            # increase the value
            self.progressBar.setValue(self.progressBar.value() + 20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @Trincatalyst if my answer solved your issue, remember to set it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark symbol on the left.